# What can be the reason for CPU load to NOT scale linearly with the number of traffic processing workers?

Tags: performance, performance-testing

We are writing a Front End that is supposed to process large volume of traffic (in our case it is Diameter traffic, but that may be irrelevant to the question). As client connects, the server socket gets assigned to one of the Worker processes that perform all the actual traffic processing. In other words, Worker does all the work, and more Workers should be added when more clients get connected.

One would expect the CPU load per message to be the same for different number of Workers, because Workers are totally independent, and serve different sets of client connections. Yet our tests show that it takes more CPU time per message, as the number of Workers grow.

To be more precise, the CPU load depends on the TPS (Transactions or Request-Responses per second) as follows.

For 1 Worker:
60K TPS - 16%, 65K TPS - 17%... i.e. ~0.26% CPU per KTPS

For 2 Workers: 
80K TPS - 29%, 85K TPS - 30%... i.e. ~0.35% CPU per KTPS

For 4 Workers:
85K TPS - 33%, 90K TPS - 37%... i.e. ~0.41% CPU per KTPS

What is the explanation for this? Workers are independent processes and there is no inter-process communication between them. Also each Worker is single-threaded.

The programming language is C++
This effect is observed on any hardware, which is close to this one: 2 Intel Xeon CPU, 4-6 cores, 2-3 GHz
OS: RedHat Linux (RHEL) 5.8, 6.4
CPU load measurements are done using mpstat and top.

Comment: Which programming language? What operating system?

Comment: The programming language is C++, and OS is Linux 6. Thanks for pointing out, will add that to question description.

Comment: I think that more information is needed here - what libraries are being used? Can you provide any useful code? (Also, [Linux 6 doesn't exist yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Linux&oldid=642677273) - the latest version is 3.18).

Comment: Amdah's law is affected by resources beyond CPU cores.  You still have only one memory bus and one network interface.  You conk out early, must be something non-subtle.

Comment: RHEL 6, of course. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To Hans Passant: > You still have only one memory bus and one network interface.
That's true, but the effect seems to be larger that one may expect.

Answer (score 3):

If either the size of the program code used by a worker or the size of the data processed by a worker (or both) is non-small, the reason **could be the reduced effectiveness of the various caches**: The locality-over-time of how a single worker accesses its program code and/or its data is disturbed by other workers intervening.

The effect can be quite complicated to understand, because:

- it depends massively on the structure of your code's computations,
- modern CPUs have [*about* three levels of cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache),
- each cache has a different size,
- some caches are local to one core, others are not,
- how often the workers intervene depends on your operating system's scheduling strategy
- which gets even more complicated if there are multiple cores,
- unless your programming language's run-time system also intervenes,
  in which case it is more complicated still,
- your network interface is a computer of its own and has a cache, too,
- and probably more.

*Caveat:* Given the relatively coarse granularity of process scheduling, the effect of this ought not to be as large as it is, I think.

But then: Have you looked up how "percent of CPU" is even defined?
Until you reach CPU **saturation** on your machine you cannot be sure that the effect is actually as large as it looks. And when you *do* reach saturation, it may not be the CPU at all that is the bottleneck here, so are you sure you need to care about CPU load?

Comment: Well, we were thinking along the same lines. Do you mean that if we explicitly bind each Worker to a CPU core, the effect will basically disappear?

Comment: @GenaL the answer is yes and no. Binding each worker to CPU core will reduce context switch, but if 2 workers constantly visit some global resources which in the same cache line, the cache of each CPU will get invalid and therefore degrade performance.

Answer (score 1):

I complete agree with @Lutz Prechelt. Here I just want to add the method about how to investigate on the issue and the answer is [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Perf is a performance analyzing tool in Linux which collects both kernel and userspace events and provide some nice metrics. It’s been widely used in my team to find bottom neck in CPU-bound applications.

the output of perf is like this:

```
 Performance counter stats for './cache_line_test 0 1 2 3':

1288.050638 task-clock                #    3.930 CPUs utilized
        185 context-switches          #    0.144 K/sec
          8 cpu-migrations            #    0.006 K/sec
        395 page-faults               #    0.307 K/sec
3,182,411,312 cycles                    #    2.471 GHz                     [39.95%]
2,720,300,251 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   85.48% frontend cycles idle    [40.28%]
764,587,902 stalled-cycles-backend    #   24.03% backend  cycles idle    [40.43%]
1,040,828,706 instructions              #    0.33  insns per cycle
                                      #    2.61  stalled cycles per insn [51.33%]
130,948,681 branches                  #  101.664 M/sec                   [51.48%]
     20,721 branch-misses             #    0.02% of all branches         [50.65%]
652,263,290 L1-dcache-loads           #  506.396 M/sec                   [51.24%]
 10,055,747 L1-dcache-load-misses     #    1.54% of all L1-dcache hits   [51.24%]
  4,846,815 LLC-loads                 #    3.763 M/sec                   [40.18%]
        301 LLC-load-misses           #    0.01% of all LL-cache hits    [39.58%]
```

It output your cache miss rate with will easy you to tune your program and see the effect.

I write a article about [cache line effects and perf](http://qqibrow.github.io/CPU-Cache-Effects-and-Linux-Perf/) and you can read it for more details.